# XCode 4.6 doesn't show current value of integers

Tags: xcode, cocoa, debugging, watch

When stepping through a loop, `NSLog(@"%d",intvar)` shows the intvar is increasing, but hovering over it still shows 0. Here, the intvar is 8 and the breakpoint has been triggered, but the debugger displays 0.
[image]
Is there some debug flag to set somewhere in the project or target? When I debug, I want to be able to see the current value of any variable or object. But XCode doesn't have an easily settable "debug mode compile" or watches, like standard IDEs do.

Sometimes it doesn't even show a value for an integer, but just the name.
[image]
The Local pane is also still at 0, and sometimes it doesn't show a value at all.

All the variables' scope is method-wide, and I'm only debugging inside this method.

Is there a setting to make debugging work in Xcode or is it a bug?

Comment: Xcode 4.6 debugger is known to be *very* slow the first time you evaluate an expression, maybe your problem is related. Try to evaluate something first in the console to eliminate the first time slowdown, then check again if your values don't show in the code...

Answer (score 1):

Even I have XCode 4.6, and it worked fine for me, Check the screenshot.

You must have changed some setting,

[image]

**Wait for a while, trying to resolve*